# I've added a Lightbox jquery for my website, but I want to remove a blue border that appears everytime

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

I've added a LightBox correctly, but there's something wrong when I click a photo, because there's like a blue border in Google chrome and then another type of border in Internet Explorer that I don't want to see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaEGE.jpg

How can I remove this?

I've used this lightbox https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Thank you! :D

```
.lb-loader, .lightbox {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0
}

body.lb-disable-scrolling {
    overflow: hidden
}

.lightboxOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(Opacity=80);
    opacity: .8;
    display: none
}

.lightbox {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    font-weight: 400;
    outline: 0
}

    .lightbox .lb-image {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        max-width: inherit;
        max-height: none;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 4px solid #fff
    }

    .lightbox a img {
        border: none
    }

.lb-outerContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff
}

    .lb-outerContainer:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both
    }

.lb-loader {
    top: 43%;
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%
}

.lb-cancel {
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat
}

.lb-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10
}

.lb-container > .nav {
    left: 0
}

.lb-nav a {
    outline: 0;
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==)
}

.lb-next, .lb-prev {
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
    width: 34%;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
    filter: alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s;
    transition: opacity .6s
}

    .lb-nav a.lb-prev:hover {
        filter: alpha(Opacity=100);
        opacity: 1
    }

.lb-nav a.lb-next {
    width: 64%;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    background: url(../images/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
    filter: alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s;
    transition: opacity .6s
}

    .lb-nav a.lb-next:hover {
        filter: alpha(Opacity=100);
        opacity: 1
    }

.lb-dataContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px
}

    .lb-dataContainer:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both
    }

.lb-data {
    padding: 0 4px;
    color: #ccc
}

    .lb-data .lb-details {
        width: 85%;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.1em
    }

    .lb-data .lb-caption {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: 1em
    }

        .lb-data .lb-caption a {
            color: #4ae
        }

    .lb-data .lb-number {
        display: block;
        clear: left;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #999
    }

    .lb-data .lb-close {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background: url(../images/close.png) top right no-repeat;
        text-align: right;
        outline: 0;
        filter: alpha(Opacity=70);
        opacity: .7;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
        -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
        -o-transition: opacity .2s;
        transition: opacity .2s
    }

        .lb-data .lb-close:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            filter: alpha(Opacity=100);
            opacity: 1
        }
```

Comment: Cannot help without seeing your code.

Comment: I've uploaded the css code from that lightbox I've installed.

Comment: The only thing in the CSS you showed that even has a border set is ```.lightbox .lb-image``` and that border is solid and white.  Your image appears to be dotted and some shade of blue.  Copy and paste your source code into a .txt file and then provide that via a drop box URL or something.  Or, try an all out assault of the border with an over write like:  ```* { border: none !important; }```

Comment: might be an outline ... where is the HTML ?

Comment: I don't think the problem is from the HTML file. I think the problem comes from the lightbox.min.css file which I've downloaded from the webpage I attached in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing "the full picture" i.e. your code; you could try this:

```
.lightbox * { border: none !important; }
```

This assumes it really is a border problem and not some background image or something of that nature.

Comment: I tried to paste this code, but still appears the blue border on Chrome and the other border on IE. I don't know what's going on :( Thank you tho.

Comment: You would paste it into your style sheet.  Do you have a loaded style sheet of your own to make overwrites?  If not, you should.  If it still does not work, this is not a border issue.  Very hard to diagnose "in the dark".  Can you make a JS fiddle and share it or put it on a staging server or something?